# How to group by, regardless of a extra plus character at the end, with query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have the following table,

**[Example1]**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Category1 | 5 | Category1 |
| True | Category2 | 2 | Category2+ |
| True | Category2 | 3 | Category2 |
| True | Category2 | 6 | Category2 |

And I have the following formula

```
=query(A26:D64;"select B,max(C),D where A = TRUE group by B, D")
```

So this query groups entries by (B, D) tuple.

**Current result of Example1:**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Category1 | 5 | Category1 |
| True | Category2 | 2 | Category2+ |
| True | Category2 | 6 | Category2 |

What I want to do:
If there is a "+" character at the end of the "D" column's entry, I want to remove "+" character, and add it to the existing entry.

**Expected result of  Example1:**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Category1 | 5 | Category1 |
| True | Category2 | 8 | Category2 |

**[Example 2]**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Category1 | 5 | Category1 |
| True | Category2 | 2 | Category2+ |

**Expected result of  Example2:**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Category1 | 5 | Category1 |
| True | Category2 | 2 | Category2 |

**[Example 3]**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Category1 | 5 | Category1 |
| True | Category2 | 1 | Category2 |
| True | Category2 | 13 | Category2 |
| True | Category2 | 3 | Category2+ |
| True | Category2 | 4 | Category2+ |

**Expected result of  Example3:**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Category1 | 5 | Category1 |
| True | Category2 | 20 | Category2 |

Comment: You can cleanup the column D for `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to take the max Category2 value and add it to the sum of the Category2+ values?

If so, one option is to add a `Column E` where you check if there is a `+` at the end of the Category column and make that unique `=IF(RIGHT(D1,1)="+",ROW(),D1)`

Then run an initial query in `G1` for example:

`=query(A1:E20,"select B,max(C) where A = TRUE group by B,E")`

And a final query in `J1` to sum those results

`=query(G2:H20,"select G,sum(H) group by G")`

You can find an example in this [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nm4ayo0jdbng4UE56gyGr40y6rckFjlga2d93EcU8Z0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the example! I am working on this to implement on my board.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A26:C64\ SUBSTITUTE(D26:D64; "+"; )}; 
 "select Col2,max(Col3),Col4 
  where Col1 = TRUE 
  group by Col2,Col4
  label max(Col3)''"))
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

**Change the range once you try the syntax.**

```
=QUERY({query(A18:D21,"select B,max(C),D where (A = TRUE and D<>'Category2+') group by B, D");query(A18:D21,"select B,C,D where D = 'Category2+'")},"Select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1")
```

Result:
[image: Example]

References:

- [How to Combine Two Query Results in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/combine-two-query-results/)
- [How to Use Nested Queries in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/google-sheets-nested-query/)

Comment: ={query(A26:D64;"select B,max(C),D where (A = TRUE and D<>'Category2+') group by B, D");query(A26:D64;"select B,C,D where D = 'Category2+'")}

gives the error "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an array literal was missing values for one or more rows"

Comment: On the other hand "Category2" string was an example, It shouldn't be hardcoded.